# How to reflect this phase plane?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the phase plane of $X'(t)=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
3 &1 \\ 
-4 &-1 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)X(t)$.
[image]

Which ODE system correspond to a phase plane that is a reflected image along the line $y=-2x$ of this one?

Comment: Write down the matrix of the linear transformation representing reflection about $y=-2x$: call it $T$.  The variable you want looks like $Y(t) = TX(t)$.  Work out what $Y'(t)$ is in terms of $X'(t)$.  Now use matrix arithmetic to get an equation relating $Y'(t)$ and $Y(t)$.